# How long would it take to have a domain unbanned from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, spam, marketing, spam-prevention, viral-marketing

A week ago two of my posts which link to my website were mark as spam, and after I appealed they were recovered in a day. After that I posted another link, and then all of my posts were retracted. All the posts I share are academic-y and sell nothing. I just post it in various groups (maybe too many), but still everyone likes it. Now all the shares from others (which are genuine) are gone. Since then many people has helped me appeal, but no result.

**Question:** Is there any information (statistic, rumor) about a typical length a domain is reviewed and unbanned, especially when various active accounts report it? The [Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/spam) has no helpful information.

Below is the message other people help me to appeal the ban:

> My domain “quảcầu.com” blocked by a mistake for the first time. This is my personal blog, its use is for my writing pleasure only. None of the articles is to sell anything. The most shared link is a resource that is always amongst the top most interacted posts in any group it is posted. Many people express that it is helpful to them, are eager to share to their friends, and are willing to help me appeal this ban. I found no malicious, no ads violating facebook’s policies, no spam on this website. Even the domain “quảcầu.com” decoded to “xn--qucu-hr5aza.com” looks like spam, unsafe to access the website but to remain my personal brand, I have to make it redirect just like that way. Please unblock my domain so I can continue running facebook ads for my personal blog. Thanks! – quảcầu.com
>
> [Vietnamese translation of that]

<sup>FYI: [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> I just post it in various groups (maybe too many)

You answered your question by yourself.

> I need to fake the link to prevent this in the future. Is that correct?

Can it be correct to fake link to get the possibility for extrem sharing? Is it responsible behavior in your community? Is it a kind of behavior you want experience by yourself? Probably not.

Spammy tactics have hard days. If your posting frequency is felt by community as too pushy, than you'll earn the fruits. Think about other tactics to share you content.

Comment: Please [assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence). The link is a resource that virtually no one in my country has time to do it (check my profile), and in anywhere I post the interaction rate (like/thank you comment/share) is high. In fact, after I posted a help request to help me appeal this to Facebook in one forum, people do tell that they will do that for me because it is so helpful to them. I posted it probably too much because it is true that people need it. It has been nearly a week since the ban yet Facebook still hasn't answered.

Comment: nothing against you personally, but it is a kind of fashistoid thinking: `I posted it probably too much because it is true that people need it`. What people need, they decide for themself. If you try to push things you imagine people would need - you commit violance. But this is discussion for another place.

Comment: what can I say otherwise? This is what they say themselves

Comment: I downvoted this because in my opinion it doesn't really attempt to answer the question.